# Power Query - formatting - Adding Intermediate "summary" text row

Tags: formatting, powerquery

I am transforming some data from a database, and at the end of one of the step, I need to reformat it for sending it as a document to a client. the usual template for this document has intermediate row with a sort of summary of one of the column (just text, no numbers). It would means going from first to second table here under.
Is it possible ?

| value 1 | value metadata1 | value's metadata 2 | grouping |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1st M1 | 1st M2 | group 1 |
| Second | 2nd M1 | 2nd M2 | group 2 |
| Third | 3rd M1 | 3rd M2 | group 3 |
| Fourth | 4th M1 | 4th M2 | group 1 |

| value 1 | value metadata1 | value's metadata 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| group 1 |  |  |
| First | 1st M1 | 1st M2 |
| Fourth | 4th M1 | 4th M2 |
| group2 |  |  |
| Second | 2nd M1 | 2nd M2 |
| group 3 |  |  |
| Third | 3rd M1 | 3rd M2 |

Answer (score 1):

In powerquery, try below

It groups on **grouping** and copies that into a new row in **value 1** column before expanding

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"grouping"}, {{"data", each #table( {"value 1"}, {{_[grouping]{0}}}) & _, type table }}),
ColumnsToExpand = List.RemoveLastN(List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column(#"Grouped Rows", "data"), each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))),1),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data",ColumnsToExpand ,ColumnsToExpand ),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded data",{"grouping"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: did that work for you?